# How to include and read source map file in React Native on Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I am trying to generate source maps in the Gradle build process of a React Native app and read the source map file in the application.

I used this project as a starting point: https://github.com/philipshurpik/react-native-source-maps

I didn't succeed in including it as it is, so I tried to take and modify parts of it.

In `app/gradle.build` I added:

`project.ext.react = [
  extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.map"]
]`

and indeed when I'm running the release build I see the file `index.map` under `android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release` , but when I deploy the APK to a device or emulator, I can't see this file anywhere in Android's filesystem. For that matter, I also can't see the bundle file or any files that were in `android/app/src/main/assets` and I do see in `android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release` after build.

The application code uses https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs to read the file. This is how I first check if the file exists:

`` const fileExists = await RNFS.existsAssets(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/index.map`) ``

and the file doesn't exist there. `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` returns `/data/user/0/mypackagename/files` , which is empty when I check (using adb shell with root access).

What am I missing? How do I get the source map file to a location which will be available to the application to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the `gradle.build` part was fine, and in order to read the source map file I needed to use just the file name, like so: `RNFS.existsAssets('index.map')`